# Rails on JSONB 'where' multiple search terms in nested array of objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, jsonb

I have in Rails a jsonb column on table profile with the following structure

```
add_column :profile, :properties, :jsonb, default: {}

user.build_profile(
  properties: {
    languages: [
        {name: "German", level: 3}, 
        {name: "Russian", level: 2},
        {name: "English", level: 3}
    ],
    skills: ['Alpha', 'Beta', 'Gamma']
  }
)

user.build_profile(
  properties: {
    languages: [
        {name: "German", level: 2}, 
        {name: "Russian", level: 3},
        {name: "Spanish", level: 3}
    ],
    skills: ['Alpha','Beta']
  }
)


user.build_profile(
  properties: {
    languages: [
        {name: "Italian", level: 2}, 
        {name: "Spanish", level: 3}
    ],
    skills: ['Gamma']
  }
)
```

I am able to retrieve one Language like so

```
@profiles.where("properties @> ?", {'languages': [{'name':'German'}] }.to_json)
```

and multiple skills (x OR y) like so

```
@profiles.where("properties -> 'skills' ?| array[:skills]", skills: ['Alpha', 'Beta'])
```

BUT I need to retrieve  MULTIPLE languages query term German and Russian

How can I achieve?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not familiar with JSONB but ActiveRecord does support an `and` operator like

```rb
@profiles.where("properties @> ?", {'languages': [{'name':'German'}] }.to_json).
  and(@profiles.where("properties @> ?", {'languages': [{'name':'Russian'}] }.to_json))
```

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-and

Comment: I have consider this option before made the question, but since none was able to found out an other elegeant way, i ll pick your answer. thanks